# Adding services in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to map all my repository objects to its interfaces in a single line. I don´t want to repeat my self in declarations like these:

```
services.AddScoped<Repository.Interfaces.IModeloRepository, Repository.ModeloRepository>();
services.AddScoped<Repository.Interfaces.IMunicipioRepository, Repository.MunicipioRepository>();
services.AddScoped<Repository.Interfaces.IPeriodoRepository, Repository.PeriodoRepository>();
services.AddScoped<Repository.Interfaces.IPlanRepository, Repository.PlanRepository>();
```

Here is a declaration of one of these repositories:

```
public interface IChatRepository : IRepository<Models.Chat>
```

I already tried something like this:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(Repository.Common.IRepository<>), typeof(Repository.Common.BaseRepository<>));
```

But gets the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to resolve service for type 'SqlExpress.Repository.Interfaces.IChatRepository' while attempting to activate 'SqlExpress.Helpers.LessonTagHelper'.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'SqlExpress.Repository.Interfaces.IChatRepository' while attempting to activate '
>   SqlExpress.Helpers.LessonTagHelper'.
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )

Comment: you could use reflection, but this seems totally reasonable...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the built in DI container in ASP.NET Core is relatively simplistic. If you would like to use more advanced features like these, then you will need to use a different container.

The example below uses [StructureMap](http://structuremap.github.io/) as that's what I'm familiar with, but it is probably also possible with Autofac, Ninject etc.

Add the StructureMap library to project.json

```
"StructureMap.Dnx": "0.5.1-rc2-final"
```

Configure the DI container to use StructureMap, with naming conventions:

```cs
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

   // other service configuration

   // Create a new StructureMap container        
   var container = new Container();

   container.Configure(config =>
   {
       //add all the services that are already configured
       config.Populate(services);


       config.Scan(_ =>
       {
          _.WithDefaultConventions();
          _.AssemblyContainingType<Startup>();
          _.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IRepository<>));
       });
   });

   //set ASP.NET Core to use the StructureMap container to build types
   return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
}
```

It is worth checking our [the documentation](http://structuremap.github.io/) to see exactly how this works, but the default convention is to automatically register interface types such as `IMyInterestingType` with their implementation called `MyInterestingType`.

By using `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing`, each `IRepository<>` should also be registered to it's implementation.